# Can't load variables from my scriptable objects in mobile build when using Unity Visual Scripting (works in editor)

Tags: unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

I've created a brand new test scene that only contains a prefab which has a list variable containing 3 scriptable objects (located in my project Resources folder) and a script graph containing my flow which logs a count of the list to the debug log, and prints the description of the first scriptable object in the list.

Everything works fine when I test in the Unity editor, but when I build for iOS and run it on my phone, the scriptable objects data never gets loaded (in this case, the description.) You can see in the mobile console that there's an error for a missing arg which is where the description is connected.

Here's the code from my script that defines the SO:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Item", menuName = "Item")]
    public class Item : ScriptableObject
    {
        public string itemname;
        public string description;
    
        public Sprite icon;
    
        public bool consumable;
        public Targets target;
        public int range;
    
        public StatTypes stat1;
        public int stat1Value;
    }
```

This script is located in my Assets/Scripts/ScriptableObjects folder.

Unity screenshot

[image: Unity screenshot]

Here's my script graph:

[image: graph]

And here's the console log on iOS:

[image]

I'm using Unity version 2021.1.15f1
My scriptable objects are located in the Assets/Resources/Items folder
I've tried regenerating my units in the Visual Scripting project settings, and 'Item' is added as a type in the list of node types.

Everything works fine in the Unity editor.